Regression models with interpolated data?
I have a country with many cities (hierarchy: country-province-city). I have average socio-economic information (e.g. employment rate, median income, etc.) on each city only at 2010 and 2020.
In 2016, there was an election. I know what political affiliation each city had between 2010 until the election, and how the political affiliation changed after the election.
I want to make a regression model that studies how changes in socio-economic conditions can affect voting choices (I am aware of the ecological fallacy, I am only interested in studying trends at the aggregate level and not generalizing them to the individuals within the aggregate).
If I had data each year, I would try use some techniques like difference-in-difference or regression discontinuity that looks at the before/after election. However, in my case this is not available.
I had this naive idea on what to do.

I thought I could create a regression model for interpolation based on growth rate. I first start by assuming a simple longitudinal model for each socio-economic variable (assuming that it only depends on itself and not on other factors, follows monotonic/uniformly changing linear growth):

$$ \frac{x_{i,2020} - x_{i,2010}}{x_{i,2010}} = \alpha_0 + u_{px} + v_{ix} + \epsilon_{ix} $$
where:

$\alpha_0$ is the average growth rate across all cities
$u_{px}$ is the province-specific deviation from the average growth rate
$v_{ix}$ is the city-specific deviation from its province's growth rate
$\epsilon_{ix}$ is the error term

Now, for interpolation at any time $t$ between 2010 and 2020, we want to calculate what fraction of this total change should have occurred by time $t$. The formula becomes:
$$ \hat{x}_{it} = x_{i,2010}\left(1 + \frac{t-2010}{10}(\alpha_0 + u_{px} + v_{ix})\right) $$
E.g. a specific calculation:
$$ \hat{x}_{i,2015} = x_{i,2010}\left(1 + \frac{2015-2010}{10}(\alpha_0 + u_{px} + v_{ix})\right) $$
$$ \hat{x}_{i,2015} = x_{i,2010}\left(1 + \frac{5}{10}(\alpha_0 + u_{px} + v_{ix})\right) $$
$$ \hat{x}_{i,2015} = x_{i,2010}(1 + 0.5(\alpha_0 + u_{px} + v_{ix})) $$

From here, I use the interpolated values from part 1 to make a model that looks at how cities change their political affiliation before/after the election (based on their pre election affiliation and their interpolated socio-economic predictors from part 1). I thought of doing this with a multinomial logistic regression model:

$$ \log\left(\frac{P(Y_i = k)}{P(Y_i = K)}\right) = \beta_{0k} + \beta_{1k}j_i + \beta_{2k}\hat{x}_{i,2016} + \beta_{3k}(\hat{x}_{i,2016} - \hat{x}_{i,2015}) + u_{pk} $$
Where:

$Y_i$ is the post-election party affiliation for city $i$
$k$ represents each party category (except the reference category $K$)
$j_i$ is the pre-election party affiliation of city $i$
$\hat{x}_{i,2016}$ and $\hat{x}_{i,2016} - \hat{x}_{i,2015}$ come from  model 1
$u_{pk}$ is the province-level random effect for party $k$

And the probability of a city being affiliated with party $k$ after the election would be:
$$ P(Y_i = k) = \frac{\exp(\beta_{0k} + \beta_{1k}j_i + \beta_{2k}\hat{x}_{i,2016} + \beta_{3k}(\hat{x}_{i,2016} - \hat{x}_{i,2015}) + u_{pk})}{\sum_{m=1}^K \exp(\beta_{0m} + \beta_{1m}j_i + \beta_{2m}\hat{x}_{i,2016} + \beta_{3m}(\hat{x}_{i,2016} - \hat{x}_{i,2015}) + u_{pm})} $$
I have a feeling that my modelling approach is a trainwreck lol. The interpolated values have error that is being unaccounted for in the second step. I am sure there are so many problems here. Anyone up to tell me by how much I have botched this?

As far as I can tell, the interpolation doesn't get you anything. You've assumed it's linear in all cities. So, you might as well just use the change from 2010 to 2020.  I don't really understand your second step, so I am not sure what it gets you or whether it is wrong.

For the second step, I am trying to build a regression model which looks at if worsening economic conditions increase the odds of right wing counties voting left , etc. Since I dont have data exactly before and after the election, I am using interpolation
